# Why does the Conv Neural Net using Tensorflow returns same predictions for all the data points

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow

I am predicting usage quantity for different customers across different categories. Following is the network architecture.

```
#Create input placeholders
x = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, 6,15,1])
y = tf.placeholder("float", shape=[None, n_classes])

#Define Weights
weights = {
    'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(2,2,1,8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(2,2,8,12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(2,2,12,16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wc4': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(2,2,16,20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'wd1': tf.get_variable('W4', shape=(1*1*20,20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
    'out': tf.get_variable('W5', shape=(20,n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
}

#Define Biases
biases = {
    'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(8), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(12), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(16), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bc4': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'bd1': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(20), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
    'out': tf.get_variable('B5', shape=(n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
}

#Define convolutional layer
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1, reuse=True):
    # Conv2D wrapper, with bias and relu activation
    x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
    x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

#Define Maxpool layer
def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],padding='SAME')

#Define a convolutional neural network function
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  
    conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
    conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

    conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
    conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

    conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
    conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

    conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
    conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4, k=2)

    # Fully connected layer
    # Reshape conv2 output to fit fully connected layer input
    fc1 = tf.reshape(conv4, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
    fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    # Output, class prediction 
    out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
    return out

#Define Loss and Activation functions
pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)
print(pred.shape)

cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(y - pred))
#cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


#Train and Test the Model
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init) 
    train_loss = []
    test_loss = []
    train_accuracy = []
    test_accuracy = []
    summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./Output', sess.graph)
    for i in range(training_iters):
        for batch in range(len(train_np)//batch_size):
            batch_x = train_np[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_np))]
            batch_y = train_np_y[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(train_np_y))] 
            # Run optimization op and Calculate batch loss and accuracy
            opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                 y: batch_y})
            loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                              y: batch_y})
        print("Iter " + str(i) + ", Loss= " + \
                      "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                      "{:.5f}".format(acc))
        print("Optimization Completed")

        # Calculate accuracy for all test data
        test_acc,valid_loss = sess.run([accuracy,cost], feed_dict={x: valid_np,y : valid_np_y})
        train_loss.append(loss)
        test_loss.append(valid_loss)
        train_accuracy.append(acc)
        test_accuracy.append(test_acc)
        print("Testing Accuracy:","{:.5f}".format(test_acc))

        summary_writer.close()

    predictions = pred.eval(feed_dict = {x:valid_np})
```

What I have observed is if I change the cost function to sigmoid or softmax cross entropy, the predictions are negative and huge numbers (to the order of 10^12) the response value range is between 0.05 - 7900 so I'm pretty sure this is wrong prediction. When I change the cost function to MSE the predictions are comparable to response variable. However sometimes all the input data points have exactly identical predictions. If somebody understands what might be happening please explain. I really appreciate any input.

Note : This question is meant to understand the outcome of neural network conceptually and not looking for suggestions on improving the model.

Comment: @Tim - I'm not asking what to do in order to improve the results. I'm trying to understand conceptually why this might be happening. Kindly unmark this question. Thanks

Comment: If the linked question does not answer your problem, please edit your question to tell us precisely what is your question. I'm afraid that "how to improve this model" is too broad for Q&A site like this.

Comment: @Tim - I understand, I'm not asking how to improve the model. I want to know why following observed behavior is occurring.

"What I have observed is if I change the cost function to sigmoid or softmax cross entropy, the predictions are negative and huge numbers (to the order of 10^12) the response value range is between 0.05 - 7900 so I'm pretty sure this is wrong prediction. When I change the cost function to MSE the predictions are comparable to response variable. However sometimes all the input data points have exactly identical predictions."

It's more for my conceptual understanding.

Comment: Sometimes when? What is your data?